# RC522 using SPI in STM32F4 with RTOS

Tags: c, embedded, project, stm32, stm32f4discovery

this is the task using RC522 SPI

```
void StartDefaultTask(void const * argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 5 */
  /* Infinite loop */
  for(;;)
  {
      if (!MFRC522_Request (PICC_REQIDL, str))
      {
          if (!MFRC522_Anticoll(str))// DOC MA THE TU RC522
              {
              //Do somthing...
              //...
              }
      }
    osDelay(1000);
  }
```

i'm having trouble in read Variable "str".
if i use this function alone, without RTOS, it will run perfectly. But by included to the task, it won't read.
i'm also have this when debug
[image]

this is the funtion for RC522 ID

```
uint8_t MFRC522_Anticoll(uint8_t* serNum) {
    uint8_t status;
    uint8_t i;
    uint8_t serNumCheck = 0;
    uint16_t unLen;

    MFRC522_WriteRegister(MFRC522_REG_BIT_FRAMING, 0x00);                                               // TxLastBists = BitFramingReg[2..0]
    serNum[0] = PICC_ANTICOLL;
    serNum[1] = 0x20;
    status = MFRC522_ToCard(PCD_TRANSCEIVE, serNum, 2, serNum, &unLen);
    if (status == MI_OK) {
        // Check card serial number
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) serNumCheck ^= serNum[i];
        if (serNumCheck != serNum[i]) status = MI_ERR;
    }
    return status;
}
```

Comment: "_I'm also have this when debug_" relates to a different issue.  Best not to ask two separate questions in one post on SO.

Comment: "_won't read_" is an inadequate description.  Does teh function return without modifying `str` or does it fail to return, or does it modify `str` with something other than expected data?  Either way, there is a lot of "unseen" code here in the `MFRC522_...` API.  I think your question would better focus on fixing the debugger issue so you can fix the code error yourself.

Comment: The content of the "Details>>" button in the message box might be helpful.  The error message is from your IIDE - so it would be helpful is you stated what that was (including version information). Have you previously been able to launch the debugger?  What debug hardware are your using?  Have you tried "connect under reset" rather then "Normal" - that is necessary on some boards.

Comment: Is the task's stack big enough?  Maybe you're getting a stack overflow when using the RTOS.

Comment: the problem is how to fix the code. It will read card ID from RC522 normally without RTOS, but when im using RTOS, the return of card ID will be 0